# Postgres SQL Database Recovery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am recovering a corrupted database, which may not really of had problems, but the server did.

The host has restored a backup of the VM image (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), however, its 10 days old, which is pretty disappointing.

So what i decided to do is copy the old recovered database located in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base`

I restarted the VM and postgresql, but the old data only showed!

So i have been repeatedly reindexing the database, the missing data is starting to appear.

Does anyone have in more tricks in this area?

Comment: If it's a crash consistent backup that may work, but you need `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main` and all its subdirectories, not just `base`.

Comment: When i add these other directories it causes problems. Not sure why.

Comment: Read this and act on it before doing anything else: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: You *must* restore the whole directory, not just `base`. It might seem to be kind-of working if you just copy `base` (if you're really lucky) but it'll be horribly corrupted. Restore the *whole* data directory from the recovered VM, try to start the DB, and report the errors that appear in the PostgreSQL logs not just "it causes problems, not sure why"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11030173/398670

Comment: I reindexed the tables. It appears to be fully functioning. I have not received any database errors. What does the other files contain?